# Nginx Caching for Server side rendering (SSR) pages created with react + nextjs

Tags: javascript, nginx, caching, next.js, server-side-rendering

I created an application that some of my pages are rendered on server side, but I realized that something was not going well. I can see that the requested pages rendered as usual on my browser; but I sent a **CURL request** to my page and the response was stored in a file, `mypage.htm`, then  I opened the `mypage.htm`, the **page was not rendered as expected**.

**The first reason of why I have chosen SSR is **caching the responses into a frontier layer like Nginx or Varnish**.**

I'd like to know about that does Nextjs provide fully server side rendered pages or does it just joking and playing its role in the industry like an Holy wood star as "Hey I render things on server Side, but things aren't rendered on server side actually!" or i missed something in detail!

Answer (score 3):

Next.js supports 3 methods,

1. SSR (when you define `getInitialProps`)
2. SSG - static site generation, created a **static** page at BUILD time (when you define `getStaticProps`)
3. Static site Re-Generation, creates a static page at BUILD time, and when the data is changes RE generate the static page again (when you define `getStaticProps` + `revalidate` field in it)

For more info read [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching)

Comment: I will check asap. Thanks @felixmosh